# C# wrapper - How to import variables/constants from the CoreMIDI framework

Tags: c#, interop, wrapper, midi, coremidi

Over the last week I started writing a C# wrapper for the CoreMIDI API, present in MacOS. I'm using the `DllImport` attribute to access the methods that I need.

Unfortunately, there are a couple of methods (such as `MIDIObjectGetStringProperty`) that use constants (such as `kMIDIPropertyName`) as input variables.

What should I do to import these constant variables from the framework? Or is there another way to access the constant data? I've already been to the CoreMIDI source code but couldn't find a thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's going to hurt. Interop with C is easy, interop with Objective C is not. `MIDIObjectGetStringProperty` takes a `CFString`, which is not a type you can comfortably interop in C#. There are no simple constants (at least not what .NET would call constants); instead the various strings are declared in the library. There is some specialized tooling for Objective C interop (like [Dubrovnik](https://github.com/ThesaurusSoftware/Dubrovnik)), but even that requires some work on the Objective C end. Figure out a general strategy first before you worry about constants.

Comment: I decided to build a simple C++ API that calls the CoreMidi methods I need for the wrapper. Thank you for your answer! It helped a lot!